# Swift admob hide when i re-open the app

Tags: ios, swift, admob

i have a view controller with a banner view, i integrate there an admob ads, i followed the official tutorial, but everytime i close ( not multitasking ) and open the app it's hide. Why ? I Added in the viewdidload this :

```
 bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ]
    bannerView.loadRequest(request)
```

**EDIT**

When i run the app in my console there is :

```
    Google Mobile Ads SDK version: afma-sdk-i-v7.5.2
2015-10-27 15:16:01.146 Chat for WhatsApp[25348:2400768] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4132e00 GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0.leading == UIView:0x7fb9a4131510.leadingMargin + 120>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4137e10 H:|-(0)-[GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fb9a4131510 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4132e00 GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0.leading == UIView:0x7fb9a4131510.leadingMargin + 120>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-10-27 15:16:01.147 Chat for WhatsApp[25348:2400768] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4132db0 UIView:0x7fb9a4131510.trailingMargin == GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0.trailing + 120>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4137e60 H:[GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fb9a4131510 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4132db0 UIView:0x7fb9a4131510.trailingMargin == GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0.trailing + 120>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-10-27 15:16:01.172 Chat for WhatsApp[25348:2400768] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fb9a4129e50 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fb9a41321c0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fb9a4129e00 _UILayoutGuide:0x7fb9a41321c0.bottom == UIView:0x7fb9a4131510.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4132e50 V:[GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fb9a41321c0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a41380d0 V:[GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0]-(1)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fb9a4131510 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4132e50 V:[GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fb9a41321c0]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-10-27 15:16:01.180 Chat for WhatsApp[25348:2400768] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a2f07260 H:[GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0(320)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4137e10 H:|-(0)-[GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fb9a4131510 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a4137e60 H:[GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fb9a4131510 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a2c1edf0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fb9a4131510(768)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb9a2f07260 H:[GADBannerView:0x7fb9a2f128e0(320)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

it can be a constraints problem? i have a WKWebView and a View(banner view)

this are my constraints :

```
  let viewsDictionary = ["top":webView, "bottom":bannerView]

    let view_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[top]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    let view_constraint_H2:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[bottom]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
    let view_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[top]-[bottom]-1-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

    view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
    view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H2 as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
    view.addConstraints(view_constraint_V as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
```

in advance my banner view is not 320x50 as i use it for iPad
please help me, thank you very much in advance

Comment: what do you mean close and open ? does it show up at all ?

Comment: when i close the app, like a tap on the home button and then i return on my app, the ads hides

Comment: try logging the bannerview when you re-open app, do you  have set the constraints ? It might be fetching new ads or hidden because of layout error

Comment: @ogres please see the edits, thank you

Comment: try this [link](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/display-ads-in-your-application-with-google-admob/) had same problem and it helped..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading` with `NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0)`, because it will try to add non-necessary constraints. Remove all constraints from Storyboard

First of all, declare new Constraint for Ad height in your ViewController, then create the constraint

```
let viewsDictionary = ["top":webView, "bottom":bannerView]

let view_constraint_H:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[top]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
let view_constraint_H2:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[bottom]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)
let view_constraint_V:NSArray = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[top]-[bottom]-1-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary)

view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
view.addConstraints(view_constraint_H2 as! [NSLayoutConstraint])
view.addConstraints(view_constraint_V as! [NSLayoutConstraint])


constraintAdHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: getAdsHeight())
view.addConstraint(constraintAdHeight)
```

for this , you will need `getAdsHeight()` method,

```
func getAdsHeight() -> CGFloat {
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation)) {
        return CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height
    } else {
        return CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape).height
    }
}
```

and each time layout/orientation changes, you can update the height.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews();
    self.constraintAdHeight.constant = getAdsHeight()
}
```

You can also set the constraint.constant to 0 when Ads is hidden ( failed to load )

Comment: My code is in swift, and anyway i set the constraints but the ad doesn't show anymore...

Comment: ok i deleted the constraints i had in the storyboard for the banner view, but now the ads is no more at the bottom, but now works even if i close.. how i can fix that please?

Comment: thank you, but it crash in this line: view.addConstraint(constraintAdHeight)

Comment: yes, because I had a placeholder UIView() instead of bannerView, try now with bannerView

Comment: did you copy all the functions? did you override will layoutsubviews ? try logging the ad view and lets see its frame/properties

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93511/discussion-between-marcoc-and-ogres).

Comment: This was helpful for me [link](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/display-ads-in-your-application-with-google-admob/)